# C++ Member Functions and Constructor problems

Tags: c++, class, function, member

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Car{
private: 

public: Car(int, string, int);
    Car(){}  //default constructor 
    void setbrake();
    void setacc();
    int year,speed;
     string make;

};


Car::Car(int year, string make, int speed = 0) //constructor with parameters
{ 
cout << "Enter your car's year." << endl;
cin >> year;
cout << "Enter your car's make. " << endl;
cin >> make;
cin.ignore();
speed = 0; }

void Car::setbrake(){  //first function
    speed = speed - 5;
    cout << "Your " << make << " is traveling at " << speed;
    cout << " MPH.";}

void Car::setacc(){   //second function
    speed = speed + 5;
    cout << "Your " << make << " is traveling at " << speed;
    cout << " MPH.";}




int main()
{
Car car1(0,"s");
cout << car1.make;
cout << car1.speed;
cout << car1.year;
car1.setacc();



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I'm having a problem getting my variables to display in my two member functions, and it doesn't display anything in main. 
The speed variable always comes out to 49898575 <-- some randomly high number like that, and I assume I initialized it to 0. 
I've been stuck on this all week.
How do I connect my class private variables and my member functions. 
I thought my constructor with parameters would take care of that problem, but obviously not.
Can someone please take the time to critique this code for me. I'm going to pull my hair out.

Here's the problem that was assigned for class, and this is what I'm aiming to do, but I'm not catching on to classes and member functions, and how they work together.

Write a class named Car that has the following member variables:
• year. An int that holds the car’s model year.

• make. A string that holds the make of the car.

• speed. An int that holds the car’s current speed.

In addition, the class should have the following member functions.

• Constructor. The constructor should accept the car’s year and make as arguments
and assign these values to the object’s year and make member variables. The constructor
should initialize the speed member variable to 0.

• Accessors. Appropriate accessor functions should be created to allow values to be
retrieved from an object’s year, make, and speed member variables.

• accelerate. The accelerate function should add 5 to the speed member variable
each time it is called.

• brake. The brake function should subtract 5 from the speed member variable each
time it is called.

Demonstrate the class in a program that creates a Car object, and then calls the accelerate
function five times. After each call to the accelerate function, get the current speed of the car and display it.

Then, call the brake function five times.

After each call to the brake
function, get the current speed of the car and display it.

Comment: Does not compile, let alone give the results you describe.

Comment: Your ctor is declared with three parameters but list only two in the definition. I'm pretty sure this shouldn't compile, unless you're not showing the whole code, in which case I would assume you're calling a different constructor than expected, which doesnt initialize speed

Comment: I uploaded the version that would compile.

Comment: Do you really want a constructor that depends on console IO?

Comment: Sorry about that, I started experimenting a bit before I posted

Comment: thats what my assignment calls for

Comment: @bigdog225, You're misunderstanding. Accepting them doesn't mean it internally gets input. That's for the creator to do and pass in.

Comment: so I have to set initial values?

Comment: I wish I had a better CS teacher, he just runs through power points and vaguely answers questions.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the values of your parameters, which shadow your members, leaving both ints uninitialized (the string will be an empty string).

The better option is to use different names:

```
Car::Car(int y, string m, int s = 0)
```

You could, however, use `this`:

```
this->speed = 0;
```

I'd recommend a constructor initializer list, though, which doesn't require either, and doing it in the order they're declared in the class:

```
Car::Car(int year, string make, int speed = 0)
    : year(year), speed(speed), make(make) {}
```

Ideally, I would do something like this, with tweaking depending on what else it's meant to be used for (I'll keep it C++03):

```
class Car {
    int year_;
    std::string make_; 
    int speed_;

public: 
    Car(int, const std::string &, int);
    void brake();
    void accelerate(); 
    void printInfo() const;
};

Car::Car(int year, const std::string &make)
    : year_(year), make_(make), speed_() {} //speed should always be 0

void Car::brake() {
    speed_ -= 5; //consider ensuring it stays at or above 0
}

void Car::accelerate() {
    speed_ += 5;
}

void Car::printInfo() const {
    std::cout << "Your " << make_ << " is traveling at " << speed_ << " MPH.";
}
```

You'll have to figure out exactly what the default constructor should do if you want one. I used a constructor initializer list to *initialize* the data members, I separated the printing from the accelerating/braking, accepted const references where reasonable, and made the printing function const since it doesn't modify the object.

Comment: Ok thanks, is that the only problem you see with my code? Do you think thats what basically breaking my code?

Comment: Can you tell me why it overshadows, at a deeper level? I understand what I did, but I'm not to sure why it works at a deeper level.

Comment: @bigdog225, The parameters are in a more narrow scope. It's like doing `int i; {int i; i = 2;}`. The inner `i` is set to 2. I'm sure there's a more standard-says-so way of answering that, but it makes it a bit easier to remember across different cases.